# Safari css shows oval and not line for tab

Tags: html, css

I have noticed a little issue with my css in safari. If you compare the top picture and the bottom picture, the top picture displaying a line under the tab titles is perfect and works in all browsers except safari.

When you see the bottom picture which is safari, looks like strange oval shape. How can I get it to look like the top picture?

[image]

[image]

```
   <div class="mandem">
        <div class="tabs">
            <div class="tab-2">
                <label for="tab2-1">Description</label>
                <input id="tab2-1" name="tabs-two" type="radio" checked="checked">
                <div>

    ...

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-2">
                <label for="tab2-2">Lesson</label>
                <input id="tab2-2" name="tabs-two" type="radio">
                <div>

    ...

                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>



.tabs ul {

    color: white;
    list-style-position: inside; 
    font-size: medium; 
}


.mandem {
  background: #191828;
  color: #efedef;
  font-family: "Roboto", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 0.01em;
  line-height: 1.6em;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 100px; }


button:focus,
input:focus,
textarea:focus,
select:focus {
  outline: none; }

.tabs {
  display: block;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -moz-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden; 
}


  .tabs [class^="tab"] label,
  .tabs [class*=" tab"] label {
    color: #efedef;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 1em;
    padding: 0rem 0;
    text-align: center; }


  .tabs [class^="tab"] [type="radio"],
  .tabs [class*=" tab"] [type="radio"] {
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(239, 237, 239, 0.5);
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out; }
    .tabs [class^="tab"] [type="radio"]:hover, .tabs [class^="tab"] [type="radio"]:focus,
    .tabs [class*=" tab"] [type="radio"]:hover,
    .tabs [class*=" tab"] [type="radio"]:focus {
      border-bottom: 1px solid white; }
    .tabs [class^="tab"] [type="radio"]:checked,
    .tabs [class*=" tab"] [type="radio"]:checked {
      border-bottom: 2px solid white; }
    .tabs [class^="tab"] [type="radio"]:checked + div,
    .tabs [class*=" tab"] [type="radio"]:checked + div {
      opacity: 1; }
    .tabs [class^="tab"] [type="radio"] + div,
    .tabs [class*=" tab"] [type="radio"] + div {
      display: block;
      opacity: 0;
      padding: 2rem 0;
      width: 90%;
      -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
      -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
      -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
      transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out; }

.tabs .tab-2 {
    width: 50%; }
    .tabs .tab-2 [type="radio"] + div {
      width: 200%;
      margin-left: 200%; }
    .tabs .tab-2 [type="radio"]:checked + div {
      margin-left: 0; }
    .tabs .tab-2:last-child [type="radio"] + div {
      margin-left: 100%; }
    .tabs .tab-2:last-child [type="radio"]:checked + div {
      margin-left: -100%; }
```

Comment: Try `.tabs [class^="tab"] [type="radio"],
.tabs [class*=" tab"] [type="radio"] {
  border-radius:0; height:0; ...`